# Can Telegram notifications be disabled?

Tags: notifications, battery, battery-life, mobile-network, telegram

Can you disable Telegram notifications somehow? I am seeing a huge battery consumption since last few weeks and after upgrading to Android 5.0.2. After one day of use battery app is reporting that Telegram has kept mobile radio on for 7 hours. Using 50% of the battery used.

I use telegram rarely. I would like to completely disable notifications, but I cant find any option for that. I have tried disabling notification service and everything.

Answer (score 1):

First, AFAIK, "Notification Service" makes reference to receive notifications in Telegram about every new update (changelog or "What's new"), as well as another announcements which Telegram staff may consider important for you to know via Telegram chat.

Second, Android Lollipop has a new way to manage notifications per app. Enter Settings screen for your device and follow these steps:

[image: Settings: Sound & notification] [image: App notifications]

[image: Telegram] [image: Block notifications from this app]

**Note:** *Screenshots taken from my Sony Xperia Z1 running Android 5.0.2,  appearance may vary for your device.*

Comment: +1 I love your note at the bottom - it sounds like an ad!
Fast-Speaking Fine Print Voiceover Guy: *Terms and conditions apply. Appearance may vary for your device. See online or in-store for more details.*

Answer (score 0):

Like any other app. Go to settings >> apps >> Telegram. uncheck 'Show Notifications'

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Settings** --> **Notifications and Sounds**, and uncheck what's under **Notifications for chats**.
Then, under the **Other** section, you can uncheck **Keep-Alive Service** and **Background Connection**.

But per your battery consumption problem, it's weird and shouldn't happen. I use it regularly and it's not on my top battery consumers.